# php loops issue with repeating once

Tags: php, loops

Excuse me, i have an issue that the loop doesn't stop the repeating, so please help me with this, i need for each click one repeat only.

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" name="A"></br>
        <input type="text" name="B"></br>
    </form>
    <?php
        $ss = isset($_GET ['button']);
        do {
            echo '<form action="">
                <input type="text" name="A"></br>
                <input type="text" name="B"></br>
            </form>';
        } while ($ss)   
    ?>
    <form method="get">
        <input type="submit" name="button" value="Add ONE"></br>
    </form>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sumbit"></br>

</form>
```

Comment: If nothing changes, why do you expect the code to behave differently?

Comment: You basically 'said': do something until `$ss` is no longer evaluated as `true`, but you never change it's value... That way, the page will loop indefinitely as long as `$ss` is initially evaluated as `true`

Comment: So, what i have to do?

Comment: either re-evaluate $ss inside the loop or change your flow.

Comment: First you have to think: what are you trying to achieve? Then logically 'convert' it into php instructions that achieve your goals...

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, it's not clear from your question what you're actually trying to achieve. What are you hoping to loop through?

If you need only one form, don't use a loop.  Remove `do...while` and use a regular `if`:

```
if(isset($_GET ['button'])) {
    echo '<form action="">
            <input type="text" name="A"></br>
            <input type="text" name="B"></br>
        </form>';
}
```

If you need a variable number of forms, a `do...while` as you had is a good idea, but you need to change the contents of `while(...)` to `false` once you have all the forms you need. Your original code gave you an infinite loop because `$ss` was never set to `false`

If you're trying to do something else instead, better explain the problem and I'll adjust the answer.

Comment: Good point, i am totally confused why a loop was being used..

Comment: I used it, but when i need to add more than one form it couldn't.

Comment: @AAQ I've edited my answer.